# Prove Lipschitzianity of a function

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

Looking at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1808196/show-locally-lipschitz-and-solve-ode), I wanted to use the hint in order to show that the r.h.s is locally lipschitz w.r.t $y$

So $$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}\left\vert \frac {x}{y}+\frac {y^3}{x^3}\right\vert$$

Hence, $$\vert f(x,y_1)-f(x,y_2)\vert = \frac{1}{2} \left\vert \frac{x^4(y_2-y_1)+y_1y_2(y_1^3-y_2^3)}{x^3y_1y_2} \right\vert$$

Now, the hint by **Siminore** suggests to use the triangle inequality and the Mean Value Theorem: therefore, I obtain

$$ \frac{1}{2} \left\vert \frac{x(y_2-y_1)}{y_1y_2}  \right\vert  +   \frac{1}{2} \left\vert \frac{(y_1^3-y_2^3)}{x^3} \right\vert \leq  \left\vert \frac{x(y_2-y_1)}{y_1y_2}  \right\vert +  \frac{3}{2} M^2\left\vert  \frac{y_1-y_2}{x^3} \right\vert $$

where $M$ is the max of $y \mapsto 3y^2$ for $y$ in a neigbourhood of $y_0$.

I can't understand how to bound the first term in order to show the Lipschitz conditions. How can I move?

Comment: Locally, $x/(y_1y_2)$ is also bounded. (Just avoid zero in the second variable around the fixed point, use a compact ball.)

Comment: @dan_fulea So, if I consider $y_1,y_2$ in a compact ball that does not contain $(0,0)$, then by Weierstrass thm I have that $\frac{x}{y_1 y_2}$ is bounded, and hence lipschitz condition is fufllled. Therefore, **I can conclude that there exists a unique local solution as long as $y_0 \ne 0$**, right?